# I want to remove something using css

Tags: css

I have a slight CSS problem I cannot figure out. If you look in the row next to the word "Answer", it shows a little black rectange, (it is actually 5 little squares but you prbably can't see it clearly). I believe these are borders but I cannot get rid of it. Does anyone know how to get rid of it?

code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pSy97/) in jsfiddle

Comment: That's a lot of code to look at, and you hide most of the elements.  Could you simplify it, or does that hide the problem?

Comment: Protip, use rowspan= / colspan= for quick merging of cells etc, instead of tables-within-tables.

Comment: Thanks everybody with your answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The little black rectangle is the border of the cells of an extra table nested inside the cell. Remove the borders from those cells.

You could add the following to your css:

```
#optionAndAnswer td table td {
    border: 0px;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, you included a table in there. And the table has borders...

```
<td>
  <table>...</table>
</td>
```

so I would suggest get rid of the table in this td.

Answer (score 0):

It is a table full of hidden inputs. If you add `style="display:false;"` to the `<table>` tag it will not display those lines:

```
<table style="display:none">
<tbody><tr>
<td>
<input type="button" onclick="btnclick(this);" value="A" id="answerA" name="answerAName" class="answerBtns">
<input type="button" onclick="btnclick(this);" value="B" id="answerB" name="answerBName" class="answerBtns">
<input type="button" onclick="btnclick(this);" value="C" id="answerC" name="answerCName" class="answerBtns">
<input type="button" onclick="btnclick(this);" value="D" id="answerD" name="answerDName" class="answerBtns">
<input type="button" onclick="btnclick(this);" value="E" id="answerE" name="answerEName" class="answerBtns">
<input type="button" onclick="btnclick(this);" value="F" id="answerF" name="answerFName" class="answerBtns">
<input type="button" onclick="btnclick(this);" value="G" id="answerG" name="answerGName" class="answerBtns">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<input type="button" onclick="btnclick(this);" value="H" id="answerH" name="answerHName" class="answerBtns">
<input type="button" onclick="btnclick(this);" value="I" id="answerI" name="answerIName" class="answerBtns">
<input type="button" onclick="btnclick(this);" value="J" id="answerJ" name="answerJName" class="answerBtns">
<input type="button" onclick="btnclick(this);" value="K" id="answerK" name="answerKName" class="answerBtns">
<input type="button" onclick="btnclick(this);" value="L" id="answerL" name="answerLName" class="answerBtns">
<input type="button" onclick="btnclick(this);" value="M" id="answerM" name="answerMName" class="answerBtns">
<input type="button" onclick="btnclick(this);" value="N" id="answerN" name="answerNName" class="answerBtns">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<input type="button" onclick="btnclick(this);" value="O" id="answerO" name="answerOName" class="answerBtns">
<input type="button" onclick="btnclick(this);" value="P" id="answerP" name="answerPName" class="answerBtns">
<input type="button" onclick="btnclick(this);" value="Q" id="answerQ" name="answerQName" class="answerBtns">
<input type="button" onclick="btnclick(this);" value="R" id="answerR" name="answerRName" class="answerBtns">
<input type="button" onclick="btnclick(this);" value="S" id="answerS" name="answerSName" class="answerBtns">
<input type="button" onclick="btnclick(this);" value="T" id="answerT" name="answerTName" class="answerBtns">
<input type="button" onclick="btnclick(this);" value="U" id="answerU" name="answerUName" class="answerBtns">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<input type="button" onclick="btnclick(this);" value="V" id="answerV" name="answerVName" class="answerBtns">
<input type="button" onclick="btnclick(this);" value="W" id="answerW" name="answerWName" class="answerBtns">
<input type="button" onclick="btnclick(this);" value="X" id="answerX" name="answerXName" class="answerBtns">
<input type="button" onclick="btnclick(this);" value="Y" id="answerY" name="answerYName" class="answerBtns">
<input type="button" onclick="btnclick(this);" value="Z" id="answerZ" name="answerZName" class="answerBtns">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<input type="button" onclick="btnclick(this);" value="True" id="answerTrue" name="answerTrueName" class="answerBtns">
<input type="button" onclick="btnclick(this);" value="False" id="answerFalse" name="answerFalseName" class="answerBtns">
<input type="button" onclick="btnclick(this);" value="Yes" id="answerYes" name="answerYesName" class="answerBtns">
<input type="button" onclick="btnclick(this);" value="No" id="answerNo" name="answerNoName" class="answerBtns">
</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Here is an updated version of your jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pSy97/9/

Answer (score 0):

Actually the black square is a nested empty table that inherits the black border of td and th. You can easily test it adding this simple css rule:

`td td, td th { border: 1px solid red!important; }`